# How to send post request to server with Syncfusion React Scheduler component?

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion, syncfusion-calendar

im using syncfusion-react-scheduler package and try to make a post request with react while im adding an event to the calendar (without external buttons) and add the event to my DB.
i would like to receieve a solution from you guys, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use UrlAdaptor for performing CRUD actions on Scheduler appointments, which can be downloaded from the following link.

- **Service**: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/308326/ze/Service2137417074
- **Sample**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-scheduler-crud-sample?file=index.js
- **UGlink**: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/schedule/data-binding/#scheduler-crud-actions

**Server-side snippets**:

```
ScheduleDataDataContext db = new ScheduleDataDataContext();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
public JsonResult LoadData(Params param)  // Here we get the Start and End Date and based on that can filter the data and return to Scheduler
{
    var data = db.ScheduleEventDatas.Where(app => (app.StartTime >= param.StartDate && app.StartTime <= param.EndDate) || (app.RecurrenceRule != null && app.RecurrenceRule != "")).ToList();  // Here filtering the events based on the start and end date value.
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
public class Params
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateData(EditParams param)
{
    if (param.action == "insert" || (param.action == "batch" && param.added != null)) // this block of code will execute while inserting the appointments
    {
        var value = (param.action == "insert") ? param.value : param.added[0];
        int intMax = db.ScheduleEventDatas.ToList().Count > 0 ? db.ScheduleEventDatas.ToList().Max(p => p.Id) : 1;
        DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(value.StartTime);
       DateTime endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(value.EndTime);
        ScheduleEventData appointment = new ScheduleEventData()
        {
            Id = intMax + 1,
            StartTime = startTime,
            EndTime = endTime,
            Subject = value.Subject,
            Location = value.Location,
            Description = value.Description,
            IsAllDay = value.IsAllDay,
            StartTimezone = value.StartTimezone,
            EndTimezone = value.EndTimezone,
            RecurrenceRule = value.RecurrenceRule,
            RecurrenceID = value.RecurrenceID,
            RecurrenceException = value.RecurrenceException,
            GroupID = value.GroupID
        };
        db.ScheduleEventDatas.InsertOnSubmit(appointment);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    if (param.action == "update" || (param.action == "batch" && param.changed != null)) // this block of code will execute while updating the appointment
    {
        var value = (param.action == "update") ? param.value : param.changed[0];
        var filterData = db.ScheduleEventDatas.Where(c => c.Id == Convert.ToInt32(value.Id));
        if (filterData.Count() > 0)
        {
            DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(value.StartTime);
            DateTime endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(value.EndTime);
            ScheduleEventData appointment = db.ScheduleEventDatas.Single(A => A.Id == Convert.ToInt32(value.Id));
            appointment.StartTime = startTime;
            appointment.EndTime = endTime;
            appointment.StartTimezone = value.StartTimezone;
            appointment.EndTimezone = value.EndTimezone;
            appointment.Subject = value.Subject;
            appointment.Location = value.Location;
            appointment.Description = value.Description;
            appointment.IsAllDay = value.IsAllDay;
            appointment.RecurrenceRule = value.RecurrenceRule;
            appointment.RecurrenceID = value.RecurrenceID;
            appointment.RecurrenceException = value.RecurrenceException;
            appointment.GroupID = value.GroupID;
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    if (param.action == "remove" || (param.action == "batch" && param.deleted != null)) // this block of code will execute while removing the appointment
    {
        if (param.action == "remove")
        {
            int key = Convert.ToInt32(param.key);
            ScheduleEventData appointment = db.ScheduleEventDatas.Where(c => c.Id == key).FirstOrDefault();
            if (appointment != null) db.ScheduleEventDatas.DeleteOnSubmit(appointment);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var apps in param.deleted)
            {
                ScheduleEventData appointment = db.ScheduleEventDatas.Where(c => c.Id == apps.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (apps != null) db.ScheduleEventDatas.DeleteOnSubmit(appointment);
            }
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    var data = db.ScheduleEventDatas.ToList();
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public class EditParams
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public List<ScheduleEventData> added { get; set; }
    public List<ScheduleEventData> changed { get; set; }
    public List<ScheduleEventData> deleted { get; set; }
    public ScheduleEventData value { get; set; }
}
```

**Client-side snippets**:

> ```
> this.dataManger = new DataManager({
>   url: "http://localhost:54738/Home/LoadData", // Here need to mention the web api sample running path
>   crudUrl: "http://localhost:54738/Home/UpdateData",
>   crossDomain: true,
>   adaptor: new UrlAdaptor()
> });
> ```